# ask for input then skip line after

Tags: python

```
x = float(input("Please enter x value: "))
print("random next line")
```

I want the end result to look like

```
Please enter x value: 5

random next line
```

how can I skip a line after asking for user input, but not put the user input on the next line without adding a

```
print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = float(input("Please enter x value: "))
print("\nrandom next line")
```

will print a newline character (`\n`) first, giving you a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = float(input("Please enter x value: "))
print
print("random next line")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices. either `print("")` before the next line, or `print("\nrandom next line")`

Comment: But I am not sure what what is going to be coming next in my printed code, thats why I don't want to add it before "random next line" because I am not sure what it is, and print just looks so sloppy and I don't want my prof to take off points, so my only option is to add a print(""), nothing i can add to the end of the input line?

Comment: not if you want it to come after the input. You can add \n to the end of the input argument, but then the user will be typing on that "middle" line

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
x = float(input("Please enter x value: "))
print('\n' + your_next_line)
```

That way, you can pass whatever string you want and simply concatenate the \n newline in front of it.